# Purpose of with & without underscore variable view binding

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

[image: code example]

What is the purpose of defining 2 variable in this tutorial? Why don't we use 1 variable instead and accessing view with it?

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getter on the second variable (`binding`) uses the `!!` operator to assert that the variable is non-null when accessed.

Essentially the backing field (`_binding`) is nullable in order to represent the state before `onCreateView` and after `onDestroyView` whereas the getter provides an easy way to access the field without scattering null checks or assertions elsewhere in your code.